# How to download a image from the Internet through its URL?

Tags: python, image, function, console, download

I´m interested in downloading a .jpg file from the Internet. 
I would like to know a function or anyway that lets me to download files from the python console.
So I suppose the way would be more or less in that way:

```
pythondonwloadfunction(URLofthefile, rootwheresavethedonwloadedfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
with open('img.jpg', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(requests.get('<image_url>').content)
```